# How do I redirect to a URL using a Google Chrome Extension & Content Script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently building a Google Chrome extension which tests for certain patterns and if found, redirects them to a new URL.

I've gotten the pattern checking done via a content script, and now I'm not sure how can I proceed with getting the redirect done. Any suggestions ?

Comment: @jmort `window.location` doesn't work since content scripts are unprivileged. Further more, `window.location.href` returns the current location, but it is not a method so I cannot overwrite it.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Send redirect url from a content script to a background page:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({redirect: "http://redirect"});
```

In a background page update tab's url which would cause redirect:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender) {
    chrome.tabs.update(sender.tab.id, {url: request.redirect});
});
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Found this as well -> http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#event-onRequest & the video over here -> http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html

Comment: Hi Calvin.   I know this is an old post but I appreciate your suggestion and I see it work if i try to redirect to "yahoo.com", but if I send a specific URL (which I confirmed is correct with console.log), Chrome redirects me to the URL with the extensionID prepended to the URL. Any ideas how to resolve this?  So URL ends up being something like: chrome-extension://injepfpghgbmjnecbgiokedggknlmige/mywantedurl.hmtl

Comment: This seemed to have no effect for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to **access a file inside your WebExtension**, you can add the file and its prerequisites to [`web_accessible_resources`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) in `manifest.json`, as in

> ```
> {
>   ...
>   "web_accessible_resources": [
>     "images/*.png",
>     "style/double-rainbow.css",
>     "script/double-rainbow.js",
>     "script/main.js",
>     "templates/*"
>   ],
>   ...
> }
> ```

Answer (score -5):

Ive not worked with Google Chrome extensions... but you may be able to use one of [these ways](http://ntt.cc/2008/01/21/5-ways-to-redirect-url-with-javascript.html).

As I understand, these extension APIs allow you to  inject javascript into the page... after that its simple manipulation of window.location ...

Comment: As mentioned, content scripts are unprivileged, so it's not possible to do that