# How do I make a Google chrome extension redirect to a specific website?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

here is the manifest file

```
{
  "name": "NSHQ ChatBox",
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "NSHQ Chat.",
  "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "logo.png",
      "chrome.windows.create" : "http://nshq.darkbb.com/chatbox/chatbox.forum?"
  },
  "permissions": [
      "http://nshq.darkbb.com/chatbox/chatbox.forum?"
  ]
}
```

The Webpage i want to redirect it to is : http://nshq.darkbb.com/chatbox/chatbox.forum?

I am very new to this kind of thing so i wonder if anybody can help me, much appreciated

Comment: Could you please explain what do you mean by redirecting exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859689/how-do-i-redirect-to-a-url-using-a-google-chrome-extension-content-script) the answer you're looking for?

Answer (score -1):

```
window.location.assign('http://yourlink.com');
```

does that work for your needs?