# Change part of href url link via javascript or Jquery

Tags: jquery, url, href

Sorry if this is a duplicate, I know that there are many answers to this but somehow I cannot get any code to work.

I frequently visit a site that has href links on the page like this:

```
http://www.brilla.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=19482&p=719192
```

but I want to change all links to change to the IP address like this:

```
http://56.195.106.162/forum/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=19482&p=719192
```

I have tried using a Jquery in a bookmarklet (http://benalman.com/code/test/jquery-run-code-bookmarklet/) but nothing seems to work.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers.

This answer does exactly what I need [How do I redirect to a URL using a Google Chrome Extension & Content Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859689/how-do-i-redirect-to-a-url-using-a-google-chrome-extension-content-script/13291579#13291579)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this might work but just try it.

You can set a value of any html attribute by using the `.attr()` function.

So you might write:

```
$('.linkClass').attr('src', 'the new value of the src');
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Tried `$('.linkClass').attr('www.brilla.com', '56.195.106.162');` but id does nothing (I'm using Chrome)

Comment: @james young No that is not the correct query, do not replace the `.attr('src')` to anything just the `the new value of the src` to your value.

Comment: You can verify the new assigned src by doing an alert like: `alert($('.linkClass').attr('src', '56.195.106.162'));`

Comment: Thanks, upon closer inspection I think I must change the src since the href links take the src from the site automatically -- Unfortunately `$('.linkClass').attr('src', '56.195.106.162');` still does not work

Comment: change `src` to `href`

Comment: [How to change the href for a hyperlink using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179713/how-to-change-the-href-for-a-hyperlink-using-jquery) refer to this link