# How to redirect url chrome-extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-oauth

I'm using Google Developer Console and Oauth to develop a chrome extension so that user can login by google account.But I can not redirect to url like this

`chrome-extension://<id>`.

So how can this be solved ?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older question, but I wondered too. You have to use the built in chrome API for accessing your extension's HTML.

```
chrome.extension.getURL('options.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

Send redirect url from a content script to a background page:

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({redirect: "http://redirect"});
```

In a background page update tab's url which would cause redirect:

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender) {
    chrome.tabs.update(sender.tab.id, {url: request.redirect});
});
```

Refer: [How do I redirect to a URL using a Google Chrome Extension & Content Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859689/how-do-i-redirect-to-a-url-using-a-google-chrome-extension-content-script)