# Redirect to url Using Google chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am new to **Google Chrome Extensions**. I have created a button in my extension. With that button I want to redirect the user to another site (like "www.example.com"). 
I have the following code which I wrote for the redirection, but it doesn't work.

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859689/how-do-i-redirect-to-a-url-using-a-google-chrome-extension-content-script).

*manifest.json*

```
{
    "name": "Popup ",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "0.1",
    "description": "Run process on page activated by click in extension popup",
    "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },

    "permissions": [
        "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
    ]
}
```

*popup.html*

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
            body { min-width:250px; text-align: center; }
            #click-me { font-size: 15px; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id='click-me'>Click Me!</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

*background.js*

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender) {
    chrome.tabs.update(sender.tab.id, {url: request.redirect});
});
```

*popup.js*

```
function clickHandler(e) {

    chrome.extension.sendRequest({redirect: "https://www.google.co.in"});
    alert("url");

    this.close();
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.getElementById('click-me').addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
})
```

Do you have any idea why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you use [background pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages), then you need to declare the background script (background.js in your case) in the manifest file:

```js
  "background": {
      "scripts": [ "background.js" ]
  },
```

Your example will not work though, because [`sender.tab`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#type-MessageSender) is only defined if the request came from a tab or content script, not from the popup.

In your example, there is no need for a background page at all, you can just use the [`chrome.tabs`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) API directly from the popup page:

```js
function clickHandler(e) {
    chrome.tabs.update({url: "https://example.com"});
    window.close(); // Note: window.close(), not this.close()
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById('click-me').addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
});
```

Comment: What i have to do if i want  to open the given url in next tab?

Comment: @Jatt.net-Born2Code Use [`chrome.tabs.create`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-create).

Comment: thnx for cooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooool answer,,,