# Chrome extension to help study

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to write a chrome extension to help get myself back to work (and hopefully friends too). For now, the goal is when users go to Facebook, they're redirected to a webpage that I'll make which will have a message "get back to work".

I've managed as far as setting it up, just can't manage to find the js code to redirect.

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Get Back to Work",
  "description": "GET BACK TO WORK!",
  "version": "0.1",

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "*://facebook.com/*", "*://www.facebook.com/*"
      ],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  }
}
```

content.js:

```
alert("this works");
//code here
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I suggest you read the [Chrome extension overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) (perhaps along with the pages linked from the overview). The [architecture section](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) has overall architecture information which should help your understanding of how things are generally organized/done. You will probably also want to read [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1):

just set

```
Window.location = "http://getbacktowork.com";
```

inside your content.js

Comment: Got it.
Now have a look
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859689/how-do-i-redirect-to-a-url-using-a-google-chrome-extension-content-script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859689/how-do-i-redirect-to-a-url-using-a-google-chrome-extension-content-script)

Comment: found that page already - it's for a background page but I'm running a content script. again, not completely sure what the difference is but i can't get that code to work